# Triple Integration: ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, scipy, numerical-integration

I'm trying to triple integrate a function.

```
from scipy.integrate import tplquad

S = 40
P1 = 0.37
P2 = 0.43
P3V = .05
UND = 1 - (P1+P2+P3V)    

b1 = S*P1
b2 = S*P2
b3 = S*P3
b4 = S*UND

x1 = 48
x2 = 47
x3 = 4
x4 = 1

tp1 = tplquad(lambda x, y, z: ((x**(b1 + x1 - 1))*(y**(b2 + x2 - 1))*(z**(b3 + x3 - 1))*((1-x-y-z)**(x4+b4-1))), 0, 1, lambda z: z, lambda z: (1-z)/2, lambda x,z: 0, lambda x,z: x)
```

This is throwing:

> ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power

I'm trying to integrate the function `(x**(b1 + x1 - 1))*(y**(b2 + x2 - 1))*(z**(b3 + x3 - 1))*((1-x-y-z)**(x4+b4-1))`

over the limits below:

- first, `y` goes from 0 to x,
- then, `x` goes from z to (1-z)/2,
- and then, `z` goes from 0 to 1.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed it a bit to debug it:

```
def func(x, y, z):
    print(x, y, z)
    print(b1 + x1 - 1)
    print(b2 + x2 - 1)
    print(b3 + x3 - 1)
    print(1-x-y-z)
    print(x4+b4-1)
    return x**(b1 + x1 - 1) * y**(b2 + x2 - 1) * z**(b3 + x3 - 1) * (1-x-y-z)**(x4+b4-1)
```

So when running the integration:

```
tp1 = tplquad(func, 0, 1, lambda z: z, lambda z: (1-z)/2, lambda x, z: 0, lambda x,z: x)
```

I get the following:

```
0.25 0.375 0.5
61.8
63.2
5.0
-0.125
5.9999999999999964
```

The `-0.125` from the `1-x-y-z` is the problem. You're asking Python to calculate the fractional power of a negative number `(1-x-y-z)**(x4+b4-1)`. The result would be complex in most cases.

Even if that wasn't a problem (in python-3.x the fractional power of a negative number isn't a problem!) it would still run into the `float`-requirement of `triplequad`:

```
>>> # Python-3.x
>>> tp1 = tplquad(func, 0, 1, lambda z: z, lambda z: (1-z)/2, lambda x, z: 0, lambda x,z: x)
TypeError: can't convert complex to float
```

So it seems like something is fundamentally wrong with your function (or the bounds are incorrect). That's something you have to adress. I can only guess what could be done.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I know that `1-x-y-z` should not be negative and that is one of the inequalities used while calculating the limits of the integral. The other two inequalities are `x>y` and `x>z`

Comment: Any ideas what the limits of this triple integral should be given three equations: `x>y` and `x>z` and `x+y+z<=1`